# Export database from Progress Software (1998) to Excel

Tags: database, progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I have an old database from Progress Software 1998 and there are some programs that end with the extension ".r"

I don't know the password but I need to open and export it to Excel.

How can I open it?

Database files end with .db .bi .lg.

Please if there any way to open it without password tell me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .r-files are compiled programs so those most likely won't help you very much.

The database itself might not be password protected (old Progress DBs rarely are) but you would still need a Progress runtime to access it.

You could always try to download an evaluate version from [www.progress.com](http://www.progress.com) - Progress runtimes are very good at working with older versions.

Complete (very extensive) documentation can be found here: http://documentation.progress.com/

Another approach would of course be to contact Progress Support directly.